# State-space model and/or TF for a $K$-th order linear system given the signal sequence

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, linear-systems, transfer-function, state-space

The discrete-time signal $x_n$ is a sum of $K$ discrete-time complex damped exponential:
\begin{equation}
    x_n = \sum_{k=1}^{K} \underbrace{(a_k e^{j\phi_k})}_{c_k}
    {\underbrace{e^{\{(- \alpha_k + j2\pi f_k )\Delta t\}}}_{z_k}}^n, \quad n = 0,1,...,N-1 
\end{equation}

where $a_k$ - amplitudes, $\phi_k$ - phases, $\alpha_k$ - damping factors and $f_k$ - frequencies are the parameters of the model and $n$ is the time index and $\Delta t$ is the time interval.

\begin{equation}
\label{sig_modf}
    x_n = \sum_{k=1}^{K} c_k z_k^n, \quad n = 0,1,...,N-1 
\end{equation}

where $c_k$ is the complex amplitude including the phase of the $k$-th damped exponential and $z_k$ is the $k$-th signal pole.

Such a signal will satisfy the below recurrence relation:
$x_n = p_1 x_{n-1} + p_2 x_{n-2} + ... + p_K x_{n-K} \tag 1$

For this system, I would like to know what is the state-space and Transfer-function model.
I know that the companion matrix given by the coefficients $p$'s in the first row and 1's in the sub-diagonal is the state matrix $A$.

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
    -p_1 & -p_2 & -p_3 & \dots & -p_{K-1} & -p_K \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\tag 2$

Is this correct and are my B, C and D matrices 0?
Also, what is the TF model for this system?

Given the signal sequence $x_n$, is it possible to find the state-space and transfer-function model using MATLAB lsim?

Comment: Hi: googe for "AR(p) model in state space form" and a lot of things will come up. I didn't know which one to send or which one was most useful so I'll leave that to you.

Comment: "are my B, C and D matrices 0?" I don't know -- does your system have any inputs you didn't mention?  Does it have any outputs you didn't mention?  A transfer function for a system without either input or output is boring; it is just $H(z) = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I have a signal sequence that is computed from a mathematical model - sum of damped complex exponentials.  Thus, they satisfy the recurrence relation given in (1).  This is the only information I have.  I was also thinking the tf = 0, but I wanted to make sure, whether it is feasible.

Comment: Presumably you have the initial state of the system, or some measurements of the states, and you're interested in some output or the states -- if so, *edit your question* to say so, and detail what you have and what you're interested in.

Comment: I provided the background.  I do not have information, other than the signal sequence $x_n$ and the mathematical model to generate it.  I am interested in knowing the state space model of this system.  My ultimate goal is to estimate the parameters $f,a,\alpha,\phi$ by determining the eigenvalues, which are the signal poles.

Comment: Is $K$ known, or at least assumed based on some good data?  What sort of  a range for $K$ do you anticipate?

Comment: $K$ is known.  $K=length(f) = length(a) = length(\alpha) = length(\phi)$.  I am testing the parameter estimation algorithms for different set of values for $f,a,\alpha,\phi$.

Comment: So $x_n$ and $a_k$ are, perforce, complex.  Why have you made this choice?  *Edit your question* with this information.  It's probably also a good idea to adjust your notation, since you're using $a_k$ twice, to mean two different things (the amplitudes and the system polynomial coefficients).

Comment: The polynomial coefficients are now $p_1, p_2, ..., p_K$.  The signal $x_n$ is complex, because I am considering a sum of damped complex exponentials.  Thus, the coefficients $p$'s are also complex.  I am working with complex signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have any inputs, $x_n$ is only a function of past values of itself, your B an D should indeed be zero. You don't have your output defined either. You could pick the most recent $x_n$ as output, but it could also be something else.

A transfer functions describe an input output relation. However, you don't have inputs, so also no input output relation thus no transfer function.

Comment: Could you also comment on the C matrix? is it also zero?

Comment: @Neuling look at my comments regarding the output of the system. Using your current description there is also no definition of what the C matrix should be.